# OOP implementation issue

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

The idea of the project is html renderer.
But i wanted to do it more dynamic by using Strategy design pattern(not sure if its strategy :D).

RenderStrategy:

```
public abstract class RenderStrategy
{
    private Element _RenderElement;
    public RenderStrategy(Element renderElement)
    {
        this._RenderElement = renderElement;
    }
    public abstract String Render();
}
```

Element:

```
public abstract class Element
{

    public String Render(RenderStrategy strategy)
    {
        return strategy.Render();
    }
}
```

[image]

my question is how should CompositeElement look like without the need of 
RenderCompositeElementStrategy

Answer (score 1):

I would do like this:

```
public interface IStrategy 
{
   string Render();
}

public class Element : IStrategy
{
   public string Render() {
     return "rendering for element";
   }
}

public class CompositeElement : IStrategy
{
   public string Render() {
     return "rendering for composite element";
   }
}
public class HTMLRenderer
{
   private ISTrategy ele = new Element();
   private IStrategy comp = new CompositeElement();
   private IStrategy curr;
   public HTMLREnderer(){
     curr = ele; //i set default here to Element, but you can change it base on your need
   }
   public void RenderNow(){
     Console.WriteLine(curr.Render());
     //change your strategy accordingly to your need here, may be?
   }
}
```

Comment: No i want to use it like so:
     i got div which is CompositeElement and image which is Element
i want to be able to say:
div.Render(new RenderHtml(div));
or
div.Render(new RenderText(div));

Comment: what does image render?

Comment: if its used with RenderHtml 
<img src="lnk of the img" alt="alt inf"/>

Comment: The problem is that composite elements have childNodes.
elements don't have childs 
and to render div for example u have to invoke the Render function of all of its childs, to save it to the string and if u render html u need to put that string i the middle of the string thats being produced by div's Render function and the question is how to do this smart without creating duplicate classes